# Does "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi" use encryption?

Tags: iphone, itunes, privacy

I would like to sync my iPhone to iTunes over Wi-Fi but only if the process is encrypted for privacy.  I'm still feeling a lack of trust after learning that [MobileMe synced personal data across the Internet unprotected](http://www.roughlydrafted.com/2008/08/22/is-apples-mobileme-secure/).  Is the sync encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

iTunes Wi-Fi Sync does not use encryption as it is performed on your local network only.
Your data is not transferred over the internet, so it's as secure as your local network is.

(The link about MobileMe is extremely old; Yahoo! Mail and Windows Live didn't use HTTPS.)

Comment: Thank you, my local network is only as secure as my housemates computers and IoT devices.  Since I have no control over them I have to assume they're insecure.  The days of external networks being insecure and internal networks being considered secure are long over.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to you whether or not it's encrypted. It uses your local wifi network, which you can configure however you want. If you configure it to be encrypted, by setting up WPA2, then it's encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not asking about the encryption of the wifi network, I'm asking about the traffic sent by the iPhone.

Comment: The traffic sent by the iPhone is sent over the local wifi network and nowhere else. The data on the wifi network and the data sent by the iPhone are exactly as secure as each other.

Comment: No, I don't think you're understanding the situation.  Let's suppose my housemate is connected to my WPA2 secure wifi network with her Windows XP computer.  If the synchronization data coming from my iPhone is encrypted, then a virus on her computer can't sniff the data.  If it isn't (as you're implying), then a virus on her computer could read and broadcast all of my private data to the Internet.